# Continuous state events with State Monad

Tags: scala, state, monads, state-machine, state-monad

Consider the following state machine:

```
class AudioRecorder {
  private var currentState = Idle

  def buttonTapped() = currentState match {
    case Idle => 
      currentState = Recording
      // start recording...

    case Recording =>
      currentState = Stopped
      // stop recording... 
  }
}
```

It works but is stateful and ugly.

Unfortunately, I have many situations where I need to deal with this kind of **state machine** with **continuous events**, especially in UI setting.

It seems that `State Monad` is a solution to this but so far through my learning, it is only useful when you can actually layout all the sequences of **state events** upfront so that you can connect them all through `flatMap` but not when the **state event** is continuous and non-deterministic as in this case (when user taps) - but please correct me if I'm wrong.

Although I'm not too sure if I'm asking the right question but,

**Is there a better way to model this kind of state machine that changes its behavior with continuous & non-deterministic events?**

---

I've modelled this in server-side with **Actor Model** using akka but I haven't seen anyone using actor model in UI setting.

---

Also it's worth noting that `AudioRecorder` cannot be re-created on every `buttonTapped` event to return a new instance (which could make the problem with state go away) since it retains many other states that are too expensive to be re-created on every signal.

Comment: Akka FSM implicitly storing currentState is not it?

Comment: @Mr.V. I'm not too sure but probably. I'm more of looking for a pattern that is less error-prone and if that means using another library that hides the state under the cover for me then that's fine with me. But I don't think akka is very useful in UI

Comment: Have you looked into rxscala?

Comment: @ziggystar Yeap. In fact, my entire app relies on RxScala to support MVVM pattern. As far as I can tell, this is a different problem from what FRP is solving if I'm correct. But do you have an idea to tackle this?

Comment: I think you need to clarify what you mean with "continuous" and "non-deterministic". Do you mean asynchronous? Then a solution is FRP.

Comment: @ziggystar By "continuous", I meant  "not-immediate" as in button waiting to be tapped multiple times (I had to make this clear since otherwise `State Monad` is sufficient AFAIK) and by "non-deterministic", I meant the caller is completely oblivious to the output/side-effects. For what it's worth, I could not think of any better terminologies. I'm not sure what you mean by asynchronous but the incoming events are **discrete** stream of events. Do you still think FRP is the solution to this problem if so how should I model this?

Comment: This sounds exactly like the problem FRP tries to solve. But possible there are some practical problems if you require optimizations that cannot be handled with pure functional programming. So you need local, hidden mutability. You could achieve this by creating an FRP-wrapper around your recorder that takes some incoming streams and exposes some outgoing streams, but hides the recorder.

Comment: @ziggystar That sounds like the right solution. Do you mind writing up simple code to demonstrate?

Answer (score 0):

Using FRP with `rxscala` you could encapsulate your mutable object and hide it.

It could look like the following (uncompiled code):

```
class FrpRecorder(button: Observable[Unit]) {
  private val recorder = new AudioRecorder

  button.subscribe(_ => recorder.buttonTapped())

  val recordingLength: Observable[Double] = 
    interval("100ms").map(_ => recorder.recordingLength)

}
```